# Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I just got a new PC with Windows 10 on an SSD. With my previous PC I had two hard drives, one with Ubuntu 14.04, one with Windows 7. I dual booted flawlessly with that setup. Now, I have moved these two HDD's to the new PC, but I would like to know how I can use my HDD with the existing Ubuntu on it to dual boot with the new Windows 10.

In summary:

My new PC has Windows 10 installed.

I moved my HDD containing an existing Ubuntu installation to the new PC.

I would like to set this up such that I can dual boot with windows 10 and ubuntu. Note, both operating systems are already installed on different HDD's, but the ubuntu installation was installed alongside Windows 7 originally (see extra info below). I just need to make them dual boot together. I can already boot into Ubuntu through my BIOS settings (by making the HDD containing Ubuntu the primary HDD), but I would not like to do that every time.

Extra info:

When I boot from the HDD containing Ubuntu, the grub menu comes on, with Windows 7 still as an option, but I cannot boot into Windows 7 though.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to update your grub. There might be somme work to do in the `/boot/grub` and `/dev` folders too, since I don't have dual-boot I can't be more of any help :/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to to boot into the Ubuntu OS. And then reinstall the GRUB.

I think this command will work for you if are using MBR boot records.

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

where `sda` is the disk containing Ubuntu.

Depending upon your PC, you might also have option to choose preferred OS by pressing `F12` during system startup. But if you want fancy UI, reinstall the GRUB and set its HD as primary boot device

Answer (score 0):

Just run `sudo update-grub` on ubuntu. It will search for other OSes, delete the windows 7 entry and add the Windows 10 entry. Your ubuntu HDD should be the primary boot entry in bios.

I can also recommend to edit /etc/default/grub, so it contains the following line:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

This will automatically select the last booted system as default in the grub menu. After editing this file, you need to run `sudo update-grub` again. This command will also be executed at kernel updates, so the change would apply after some time anyway.